# Angular loading indicator in select box for async

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to use angular async pipe and loading indicator, like following. But it does not work.

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
  <label>Cities </label>
  <ng-template #loading><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i></ng-template>
  <select class="form-control" formControlName="city">
    <ng-container *ngIf="cities$ | async as cities; else loading;">
      <option *ngFor="let item of cities;" [ngValue]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
    </ng-container>
  </select>
</div>
```

But if I use it like following it works:

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
  <label>Cities </label>
  <select class="form-control" formControlName="city">
    <ng-container *ngIf="cities$ | async as cities; else loading;">
      <option *ngFor="let item of cities;" [ngValue]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #loading>
      <option>Loading...</option>
    </ng-template>
  </select>
</div>
```

But I need first solution. Why does not it work?

Comment: If the `select` tag doesn't need to be rendered if the `cities` is undefined or null, why can't you move the `ng-container` outside the `select`?

Comment: @MichaelD if I move outside the select, the select box does not appearing until data load.

Comment: Yeah my point is what is the purpose of showing an empty select box? If you still wish to show it, then try to include the spinner in an `option` tag similar to the second code segment.

Comment: yes it may be actually